# Angular Functions function resulting in "could not handle the request" error

Tags: node.js, firebase, https, google-cloud-functions

I have a relatively simple Firebase function that simply creates an https request to an API and then is supposed to do a couple writes to the database. However, even though it successfully completes the API call (I can see that in the debugger of the service), it always results in **Error: could not handle request**.

**The Function**

```
  export const CreateNoonlightAlarm = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const options = {
      host: noonlightURL,
      path: "/dispatch/v1/alarms",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${noonlightToken}`,
      },
    };

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on("data", (response) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response);

        const docRef = database
          .collection("systems")
          .doc(request.body.owner_id)
          .collection("alarms")
          .doc(data.id);

        docRef
          .set(data, { merge: true })
          .catch((error: any) => console.log("docRef:", error));

        const referenceRef = database
          .collection("alarmsToSystems")
          .doc(data.id);

        referenceRef
          .set({
            alarm_id: data.id,
            system_id: request.body.owner_id,
          })
          .catch((error: any) => console.log("referenceRef:", error));

        response.send(response);
      });
    });

    req.on("error", (e) => {
      response.send(e);
    });

    req.write(JSON.stringify(request.body));
    req.end();
  }
);
```

Now, I have been at this for a while. I've tried removing everything inside the `res.on("data", (response) => {}` block except for the `response.send(response);` and I still received the error. I've also seen that many people had issues with Firebase actually updating the function and said to run `firebase init` again prior to running `firebase deploy` and that still isn't working out for me. I've also console logged things like the `request.body.owner_id` and the `data.id` to ensure they are readable, and they are. Other functions in the same file run perfectly fine when called and return what they are expected to return.

Am I missing something in allowing for this function to successfully run?

Answer (score 0):

So, after another hour of troubleshooting and digging in line by line I realized something. You can not name two things the same thing in the same function.... It never turns out well.

In line 1, I defined the second parameter in the `OnRequest()` as `response`.
In line 14, I again defined `response` as the parameter in `res.on()`.

So, as I changed the `response` on line 14 to `res` and then each corresponding use of said variable, the function began to work exactly as it was expected to be. The updated code can be found below.

```
  export const CreateNoonlightAlarm = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const options = {
      host: noonlightURL,
      path: "/dispatch/v1/alarms",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${noonlightToken}`,
      },
    };

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on("data", (res) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(res);

        const docRef = database
          .collection("systems")
          .doc(request.body.owner_id)
          .collection("alarms")
          .doc(data.id);

        docRef
          .set(data, { merge: true })
          .catch((error: any) => console.log("docRef:", error));

        const referenceRef = database
          .collection("alarmsToSystems")
          .doc(data.id);

        referenceRef
          .set({
            alarm_id: data.id,
            system_id: request.body.owner_id,
          })
          .catch((error: any) => console.log("referenceRef:", error));

        response.send(res);
      });
    });

    req.on("error", (e) => {
      response.send(e);
    });

    req.write(JSON.stringify(request.body));
    req.end();
  }
);
```